# Table Cells constraints does not load properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, core-animation

I have an animation added to my `UITableView` but while it loads for the first time it doesn't fit the constraints which I've set. They are kinda a bit squeezed - height and width of the cell.

The animation is in the delegate method of `UITableView`, `willDisplay cell` and the body looks like :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.alpha = 0
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1)

        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.alpha = 0.5
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.05, 1.05, 1)
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        },completion: { finished in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                cell.alpha = 1
                cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)
                cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        })
    }
```

My constraints for `UITableView` are set to the `superView`, and they takes whole space of it :

```
private func setupConstraints() {
        let topVehiclesTableViewConstraint = vehiclesTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
        let bottomVehiclesTableViewConstraint = vehiclesTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        let leadingVehiclesTableViewConstraint = vehiclesTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
        let trailingVehiclesTableViewConstraint = vehiclesTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)

        view.addConstraints([topVehiclesTableViewConstraint, bottomVehiclesTableViewConstraint, leadingVehiclesTableViewConstraint, trailingVehiclesTableViewConstraint])
    }
```

The method `setupConstraints()` is invoked inside method : `setupViews()` which is called in :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
}
```

Needed function in custom cell :

```
 override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
```

**EDIT**

It also loading as much times as I have visible cells animation. So if i have 3-4 cells, then the animations going to repeat 3-4 times. Which is not what I want.

Does any knows how could i fix this bug ?

[image: Shows how it is now, and how it should be]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried calling the method setupViews() from awakeFromNib?

Comment: @ShalvaAvanashvili the cell stuffs are called in `setupViews()` of the `View Controller` which have `tableView` - after cell gonna be registered.

Comment: in your cellForRow are you dequeing the cell with reuseIdentifier OR with reuseIdentifier: IndexPath ? there are 2 methods

Comment: @SeanLintern88 reuseIdentifier: IndexPath

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In willDisplay delegate method add

```
cell.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

after

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

line.

Comment: Does not change anything.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try cell.layer.removeAllAnimations() instead of view.layer.removeAllAnimations().

Comment: same result ;\.